# Identify Visual event for a control

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any event to handle then element is visual to user?

Example: There are some UI elements in the listbox but all the items are not visual, when user scrolls the listbox then element is visual. I want to identify that visual to handle read operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `LongListSelector`, rather than a `ListBox` you can use the [`ItemRealized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.itemrealized%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event to know when a virtualized item has been realized (loaded).

If you really want to know when items are visible you'll have to measure the size of the items (if they're not all the same and known in advance), the size of the area that the `ListBox` (or `LongListSelector`) takes up (it'll vary for WVGA/WXGA & 720P screens) and the `ScrollOffset` of the internal (to the control template) `ScrollViewer` to calculate which items are currently visible.